# iPad App Landscape Mode broken iOS 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ipad

I have an app for iPad and the app is only landscape right and left orientation..like printscreen:

[image: The app is only landscape orientation]

and I'm using the following code to rotate the view to landscape mode:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
 CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    [self.window setTransform:rotate];
    [self.window setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
}
```

and the xib:

[image: The xib]

It worked fine..but now in iOS 8.3 it doesn't work. It appears wrong...see the image:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

set auto layout constraints to your viewController objects.
and no need write this your code in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight];
 CGAffineTransform rotate = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
 [self.window setTransform:rotate];
 [self.window setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
```

Comment: and in xib I set orientation landscape and width 1024 height 768?

Comment: [self.window setFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen]bounds]];